# Spring - schedule task in some period of time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

Currently I'm using Spring annotation to schedule my task every 20 minutes:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1200000)
```

I want to change schedule that my task will execute only between 2AM and 5AM (still every 20 minutes).

Is it possible with Spring Scheduler? Or are there any best practices to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: alternatively you can use cron expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/20 2-5 * * ?")
```

**0/20** -> every 20mins

**2-5**  -> between 2 to 5 AM

Answer (score 1):

@Scheduled has 'cron' element so you can use full power of cron